# Возможно ли отправить запрос php file_get_contents через socks5 прокси сервер?

Tags: php, прокси, socks5

Знаю что file_get_contents можно использовать через HTTP и HTTPS прокси.
Есть необходимость использования file_get_contents через socks5 proxy-сервер. Есть ли у file_get_contents такие настройки, или только если установить на сервер софт который сделает из socks5 HTTP с HTTPS?

Я понимаю, что можно отправить запрос через socks5 с использованием curl, вот только я его использую для чего то более сложного. Хотелось бы понять умеет ли работать с socks5 именно file_get_contents.